# How to check if two rectangles intersect in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two rectangles in a WPF application. How can I check whether the rectangles intersect or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (rectangle1.IntersectsWith(rectangle2))
{
   // Do something
}
```

[Rect.IntersectWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.intersectswith.aspx)

Comment: I don't think there is an IntersectsWith() method in WPF?

Answer (score 4):

[`Rect.IntersectsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.intersectswith.aspx) might be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

try the `IntersectsWith` method.