# How to use IntersectsWith method with a rectangle defined in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, hittest, rectangles

I have this rectangle in XAML :

```
<Rectangle x:Name="MyRectangle" Height="300" Width="300"></Rectangle>
```

I want to check if it intersects with another rectangle. In [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874684/how-to-check-if-two-rectangles-intersect-in-wpf), they say that one have to use the [IntersectsWith method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.intersectswith.aspx).
But I'm unable to use it in code-behind. When I write in C# :

```
MyRectangle.IntersectsWith(
```

I get the standard error:

> "System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle does not contain a definition for 'IntersectsWith' and no extension method [...]"

I think that's because the rectangle in XAML is a `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle`, and the method is for `System.Windows.Rect`? If so, is there a way to "transform" my `Rectangle` into a `Rect`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the solution I finally used.
For each element I want to test if it intersects with others, I create a Rect containing it. Thus, I can use the IntersectsWith method.

Example (with rectangles, but you can do this with other figures, UserControls,...) :
XAML

```
<Canvas>
    <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle1" Height="100" Width="100"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle2" Height="100" Width="100" Canvas.Left="50"/>
</Canvas>
```

C#

```
Rect rect1 = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(Rectangle1), Canvas.GetTop(Rectangle1), Rectangle1.Width, Rectangle1.Height);
Rect rect2 = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(Rectangle2), Canvas.GetTop(Rectangle2), Rectangle2.Width, Rectangle2.Height);
if(rect1.IntersectsWith(r2))
{
    // The two elements overlap
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
MyRectangle.RenderedGeometry.Bounds.IntersectsWith();
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for you reply. I tried your suggestion but couldn't make it work. I overlapped two rectangles on a canvas, but when I write :
if(Rect1.RenderedGeometry.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Rect2.RenderedGeometry.Bounds)), the condition isn't "true".

Answer (score 1):

you can use [VisualTreeHelper.HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx) to test intersection don`t forget to set [GeometryHitTestParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometryhittestparameters.aspx)

`Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) hit testing only considers the filled area of a geometry during a hit test. If you create a point Geometry, the hit test would not intersect anything because a point has no area.`

Comment: Hi ! thanks for your help. I was almost able to find a working solution, especially with the example provided with GeometryHitTestParameters documentation, but in the meantime I found another solution that was easier for me to write and understand :)

Comment: @MichaëlPolla welcome :), there is no single right solution, if IntersectsWith solves the problem then you are on the right path :) you can accept your own answer ;) no hard feelings